# Backpropagation in bert

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, transformer-model

i would like to know when people say pretrained bert model, is it only the final classification neural network is trained

Or

Is there any update inside transformer through back propagation along with classification neural network

Comment: Do you mean to say pre-training vs fine-tuning?

Comment: I mean to say during pre training

Comment: could u please explain @AshwinGeetD'Sa on is there a internal update of weights during training in each encoder of bert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During pre-training, there is a complete training if the model (updation of weights). Moreover, BERT is trained on Masked Language Model objective and not classification objective.

In pre-training, you usually train a model with huge amount of generic data. Thus, it has to be fine-tuned with the task-specific data and task-specific objective.

So, if your task is classification on a dataset X. You fine-tune BERT accordingly. And now, you will be adding a task-specific layer (classification layer, in BERT they have used dense layer over `[CLS]` token). While fine-tuning, you update the pre-trained model weights as well as the new task-specific layer.

Comment: My doubt is what are those pretrained weights. Are they referring weight matrices of query, key and value?

Comment: Yes, they are weights of K,Q,V matrices, and weights of FF layers.

Comment: Thanks @AshwinGeetD'Sa , when and how are these weights(of K,Q,V matrices and FF layers) are backpropagated and adjusted?  My assumption is that first they initialize some random weights but i fail to understand when these weights are updated by back propagation

Comment: I do also assume its via MLM and NSP when error shows up its backpropagated and adjusted but how does even the feed forward layer weights are adjusted here through backpropagation! Also fail to understand is there any particular step when the Q, K, V matrices weights are updated & how are they updated.

Comment: could you please explain me on how these weights are updated?

Comment: Well, I would say the mechanism is still the backpropagation algorithm. The updates of weights depends on the derivative of the Loss. And as you mentioned, the loss is computed based on MLM and NSP.

Comment: hence when a loss is computed the backpropagation of weights starts from encoder 12 to encoder 1 for all of its Feed forward layers and Weight matrices(Q,K & V). Am i right?

Comment: thanks very much for the understanding. One final question is there any reference paper / links on how the backpropagation for bert / transformer is calculated mathematically that i can refer. If so please comment.